# Docker | set up dockerized dev environment

Tags: c++, docker, development-environment

We have a very large complex c++ app.
The app is in Github and when developing the app we have many issues developing and aligning all the requirements between all the the developers.
We were thinking about creating a dockerized development environment in order to provide a more smooth and unified development experience for the developers.

I have a few questions:

1. Does it sound like a good idea? Are there any other alternatives you think can work better?
2. What is the best way to connect a dockerized dev environment to an IDE?
3. How can we keep the environment updated with all the dependencies among all the developers? is there a way to enforce changes on the dev environment on git pull for example?
4. I saw that there is a way to copy the feature branch directly to the desktop docker and it builds some sort of image out of it - do you think this solution can be a good fit?

I am aware that these questions are a bit general but I saw all sorts of implementations to this question and I want to make sure that before I start working on this project I will know what is the best practice.

Thanks

Comment: No best practices unfortunately. Our team ended up with a few `Dockerfile`s that produce images which are then distributed between developers to make that everyone uses the same tools like compiler. To ensure that everyone builds against the same dependencies we are using vcpkg in manifest mode. You may also find this blog post interesting: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/dev-containers-for-c-in-visual-studio/